# Visual Studio Razor editing in desktop application projects e.g WPF

Tags: c#, visual-studio, razor

I am trying to edit a razor file cshtml in an WPF app project targeting .NET 4.6.
For some obvious reason that i am not aware of there is no intellisense.
I have found some guides on how to enable it in class library projects but they are all outdated and dont seem to work.

Does anyone know how to resolve this ?

Comment: I don't understand why you are editing a cshtml file in a WPF application. Are you making your own IDE? Are you confusing Razor with Xaml?

Comment: I am trying to use razor to create/render html from my custom templates.

Comment: I see, so you are using the razor engine outside of a web app. I don't know if you can expect intellisense. Have you found documentation that implies you would?